# Chartjs charts are always on top

Tags: css, vue.js, charts

I have the following problem:

[image]

When I open my `vue-datepicker` it does not display on top of the canvas.
So far I tried to change the z-index in browser dev console of the canvas. For example setting `position: relative` and `z-index:10` and setting the drop down of the picker to `z-index:50`

I can't figure out why the canvas is always on top of everything.

Here the relevant code

```js
<Tile :isLoading="!calculatedConsumption" class="col-span-1 row-span-2">
        <template #title>
            <div class="w-full flex gap-4">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-bold mr-auto">Jahresverbrauch</h1>
                <div class="w-full">
                    <VueDatePicker v-model="selectedYear" :minDate="new Date(2021,0,1)" :maxDate="new Date()" :preventMinMaxNavigation="true" :autoApply="true" :yearPicker="true" :format-locale="de" locale="de"  dark />
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template #default>
            <div class="h-72" v-if="calculatedConsumption">
                <ConsumptionChart :v1="calculatedConsumption.v1"
                    :v2="calculatedConsumption.v2" :v3="calculatedConsumption.v3"
                    :title="'Heizen'" />
            </div>
        </template>
    </Tile>
```

And the chart code:

```js
 <Pie :data="{
        labels: ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'],
        datasets: [
            {
                borderColor: ['#4ADE80', '#D1495B', '#48639C'],
                backgroundColor: ['#4ADE80', '#D1495B', '#48639C'],
                data: [v1, v2, v3],
            }
        ]
    }" :options="{
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: title,
            display: true,
            color: '#fff'
        },
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: (i) => {
                    return `${i.formattedValue}kWh`
                }
            }
        }
    }
}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the html, could you place the chart before the date picker?

z-index only works on elements in the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context), so setting the position as relative might not work, and it only sort the depth of elements at the same nesting level.
So, you can also try to change the z-index of the parents of the chart and datepicker.

Comment: It worked. I added a z-index on the parent of the title slot. It is also necessary to give it `position: relative` as z index does not work on static. Thank you